# Using Awk/Sed - Need to increment value by 5 in File ( Happens to be XML but cant use xml tools)

Tags: xml, bash, awk, sed

Ive been looking at a number of posts this morning. Some get very close to what I need.

I have a file that contains multiple lines of Network ports in use. I need to create different files and the values need to change by an increment of 5.

The file contains 100 lines ( example ) but Im only concerned with data within the "ports" tag.

Example

```
<parent>
<config>
<config1 label="Configuration1 Port">41502</config1>
<config2 label="Configuration2 Port">61160</pls_vimvom>
</config>
<ports>
<donttouch label="Base Port">1234</donttouch>
<op_var_tank label="Tank Port">41502</op_var_tank>
<pls_vimvom label="Local Port">61160</pls_vimvom>
<pls_xxx label="Local Port">11110-11120</pls_xxx>
</ports>
<extra>
More here
</extra>
</parent>
```

I need to retain the line with tag "donttouch" but change others. This line will always have the tags `<donttouch>` to `</donttouch>`

I want to replace 41502 with 41507 , and 61160 with 61165 ( and so on.. ) 
I was able to set a hardcoded value as follows: ( I need an increment )

```
sed -i -e '/<ports>/,/<\/ports>/ s|Port">[0-9a-z.]\{1,\}</|Port">1234567</|g' text2.xml
```

The Delimiter that's static is from

```
Port">
```

to

```
</
```

I need to make sure I only change the content between parent tags "" and ""

So my expected output from the above ( incrementing by 5 )

```
<parent>
<config>
<config1 label="Configuration1 Port">41502</config1>
<config2 label="Configuration2 Port">61160</pls_vimvom>
</config>
<ports>
<donttouch label="Base Port">1234</donttouch>
<op_var_tank label="Tank Port">41507</op_var_tank>
<pls_vimvom label="Local Port">61165</pls_vimvom>
<pls_xxx label="Local Port">11115-11125</pls_xxx>
</ports>
<extra>
More here
</extra>
</parent>
```

Thanks!

**Edited to reflect my complete requirement , thanks Ed*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is always that regular (e.g. not split across lines within tags) then all you need is:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[<>]" }
/<\/?ports>/ { inPorts = !inPorts }
inPorts && !/<donttouch/ {
    new = ""
    split($3,range,/-/)
    for (i=1;i in range;i++) {
        new = (i>1 ? new "-" : "") range[i] + 5
    }
    sub(/>[^<]+</,">"new"<")
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
<parent>
<config>
<config1 label="Configuration1 Port">41502</config1>
<config2 label="Configuration2 Port">61160</pls_vimvom>
</config>
<ports>
<donttouch label="Base Port">1234</donttouch>
<op_var_tank label="Tank Port">41507</op_var_tank>
<pls_vimvom label="Local Port">61165</pls_vimvom>
<pls_xxx label="Local Port">11115-11125</pls_xxx>
</ports>
<extra>
More here
</extra>
</parent>
```

Note that you CAN use a range expression (`/<ports>/,/<\/ports>/`) in awk just like you MUST do in sed due to no support for variables, but setting a flag (`inPorts`) is always a better alternative as it provides much more flexibility if/when requirements change without needing duplicate conditions or a complete rewrite.

Comment: thats the cleanest version of exactly what i need ,I've been going round and round the garden for a few hours but the substitution you've used works perfectly on a dummy test , Thank you. I will test on an actual and report back.

Comment: No problem, answer updated. FWIW I recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbin.

Comment: Thank you Ed. I will take that advice and make a purchase :) Have a great weekend.